# Using symbolic link not working to back up iPhone directly to non-default location

Tags: backup, macos, command-line, ios

There are quite a few questions about this and the answer usually involves symbolically linking the backup file to the external drive. (E.g. [Is it possible to backup iOS devices to an external drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158829/is-it-possible-to-backup-ios-devices-to-an-external-drive) or [Backup iPhone to external drive on Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127562/backup-iphone-to-external-drive-on-mac))

The command I ran was

```
ln -s /Volumes/<externaldrive>/iOSBackup/Backup /Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup
```

But when I try to backup, I get:
[image: iTunes could not backup the iPhone because the backup was corrupt or not compatible with the iPhone]

To save space I stopped doing local backups a long time ago, so there is no backup in my Mobile Sync/Backup folder to begin with which may complicate things. When I go to Devices Preferences, there is no backup to delete (as expected):

[image: Devices Preferences. The list of device backups is empty.]

It appears that the symlink process no longer works (the questions all seem to be from 3 years ago), or perhaps I've not done it correctly.

Comment: as a note, it looks like I'm going to be able to update to 10.3 over the air so I may not need this answer to update. It would still be nice to figure this out if I ever want to do a local backup.

Answer (score -1):

Edited to remove a wrong suggestion.

I have not witnessed any problems making backups while symlinking the MobileSync/Backup directory, but I have seen many problems restoring the backups with the symlink setup. With that said, it's possible the issue extends to making the backups now too. That would be interesting to verify.

Comment: oof... doesn't sound promising if restoration is useless, though I guess at that point at least I'd know how much space I need to clear to move the backup into the correct position to try to restore which iTunes leaves out when it informs you that you don't have enough space. I'll try the flipped order and see if that works.

Comment: so when I switched the arguments, I'm back to the "couldn't back up because there isn't enough space" so I think the other order is correct.

Comment: @Kelly, In the context of the OP, in reference to the order of the `ln` source and target arguments, your answer is wrong! The `ln` command you propose would create a symlink file on the external drive not the internal drive where it actual needs to be in order to follow it to the new location being on the external drive.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, I am wrong! For some reason my brain wanted to make a symlink to backup yesterday instead of making a backup a symlink. I will however go test whether the symlink to external now causes backups to fail on my Mac to see if this iTunes/BackupAgent2 issue has extended to making the backups too.

Comment: @dwightk I can still make a backup with the symlink to external configuration, so that is not it either, so let's get more basic :)
In your /Volumes/<externaldrive>/iOSBackup/Backup, is there a folder of a partial backup of your iPhone in there (it may not be enough to be listed in iTunes Preferences)? If so delete it and try again. Also, how quickly do you get the corrupt backup error?

Comment: @Kelly, your edit "Edit: **No, the above is wrong, and the arguments were not backwards.**" makes no sense! How can the above be wrong and the arguments not be backwards? **The arguments are backwards!** Your `ls` command **does not create** a link on the internal drive to the external location of the backup. That command would create a symlink called `Backup` at `/Volumes/<externaldrive>/iOSBackup/`, assuming the `Backup` dir doesn't already exist, which is the exact opposite of what needs to be done. You might want to read the man page for `ls` again.

Comment: @Kelly, When iTunes looks to `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` the `Backup` at `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/` needs to be the symlink file that points to `/Volumes/<externaldrive>/iOSBackup/Backup` where the `Backup` at `/Volumes/<externaldrive>/iOSBackup/` is a directory, not a symlink like your `ls` command, as written, would do if only `/Volumes/<externaldrive>/iOSBackup/` exists. Otherwise if `/Volumes/<externaldrive>/iOSBackup/Backup` already exists as a directory then a `Backup` symlink file is created in that `Backup` directory and that's not what's needed!

Comment: @user3439894 I was trying to agree with you and say I was wrong before. I will just edit the original thing to take it out entirely.